# Firing a trigger at regular intervals of 1 minute

Tags: sql-server, triggers, event-triggers

I have written a trigger code. It is given below.

```
create trigger trg1 on tb_g2 for insert as begin declare @mid int
select @mid=mid from tb_g2 where biddate>'2014-05-03 20:50:52'
insert into tb_g5(pid) values(@mid)
end
```

EDIT

```
create trigger trg1 on tb_g2 for insert as begin declare @mid int
select @mid=mid from tb_g2 where biddate>getdate()
insert into tb_g5(pid) values(@mid)
end
```

The problem is the this trigger works only when an insert operation is done on table `tb_g2`; I need to execute trigger `trg1` at regular intervals say 1 minute and check whether `biddate> '2014-05-03 20:50:52'`.

Instead of `'2014-05-03 20:50:52'` this particular date and time I need to get current date and time from the server and check whether `biddate>current date and time` from server.

Suppose `biddate` is `2014-06-03 08:11:00` and current date overcomes `biddate at 2014-06-03 08:11:01`, So I need to enter the mid value into `tb_g5` when current date and time becomes `2014-06-03 08:12:00`.

So I need to check current date and time with `biddate` at each 1 minute interval and if current date is higher insert mid value into column `pid` of `tb_g5`.

Comment: Why not compute the value when you need to interrogate the database instead?

Comment: @EdHeal Can we give any loops such as for loop or while loop in the trigger execution statements?? I just need to know about it..